# What are `spring-boot-starter` jars?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

In Spring Boot, there are some jars on the pattern of `spring-boot-starter`. All these jars do not contain any packages. What is their use?

In Maven POMs, the following dependencies are added:

- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web
- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator
- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security

Which Spring Boot jars do I actually need to use the functionality in these jars? My project does not have any dependency management. My project is a Spring MVC application which uses Spring Security.

Comment: See the documentation: [Spring Boot - Starter POMs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-starter-poms)

Comment: @Jesper What about the second part of my question?

Comment: If you are not using Maven then the starter POMs will not be useful to you - you'll have to add all the JARs with the actual Spring Boot classes to your classpath. I'd highly recommend using an automatic build tool like Maven or Gradle, because keeping track of everything manually is quickly going to become very cumbersome.

Comment: @Jesper: I think you should have made your comments as an answer and this should have been the *accepted* one, including the link to the list of the `spring-boot-starter-xxx` artifacts, just not bound to a specific Spring Boot version so it does not become obsolete: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-starter

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Those dependencies are meant to provide a unified entry to an ad-hoc skeleton project with all **needed dependencies**.

They should usually be inherited from your project descriptor (*pom.xml*) so that you get all parent dependecies with configured versions. No more burden to be done on the developer side:

> Starter POMs are a set of convenient dependency descriptors that you can include in your application. You get a one-stop-shop for all the Spring and related technology that you need, without having to hunt through sample code and copy paste loads of dependency descriptors. For example, if you want to get started using Spring and JPA for database access, just include the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency in your project, and you are good to go.

*Reference, **[Spring Boot Starter POM](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-starter-poms)**.*

### Edit:

Those POMs can be used to synthesize the dependencies that can be used for a certain kind of project, e.g. for a simple Spring MVC project, the following artifacts are to be included (Read from *spring-boot-starter*, *spring-boot-starter-web*, *spring-boot-starter-security* respectively):

- Spring Boot artifacts:

  - *org.springframework.boot:spring-boot*
  - *org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure*
  - *org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging*
- Spring Core, Web, MVC, Security artifacts:

  - *org.springframework:spring-core*
  - *org.springframework:spring-web*
  - *org.springframework:spring-webmvc*
  - *org.springframework:spring-beans*
  - *org.springframework:spring-context*
  - *org.springframework:spring-expression*
  - *org.springframework:spring-aop*
  - *org.springframework.security:spring-security-config*
  - *org.springframework.security:spring-security-web*
  - *org.hibernate:hibernate-validator*
  - *com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind*

The artifacts can be found seamlessly navigating search results in the [maven central repository](http://search.maven.org/).

*Note that this may not be a full fledged reference list as some components may be mising thus the artifacts are subject to be updated.*

Comment: The project I am working on does not have any dependency management. As a result, I have to add the jars manually. Could you tell me which jars to add for these starter POMs?

Comment: You should at must use a dependency management tool (I recommend maven already), otherwise you will loose all the gain brought by Starter POMs and those won't look more that text descriptors for you. In order to know what dependencies to hook, you should first ask what kind of application are you working on and that would bring more clarity to the main thread.

Comment: I have edited the question for more clarification about the my app. All I need are the names of the Spring Boot jars which are referenced by the jars I mentioned.

Comment: The starter jars themselves are effectively empty as far as your application is concerned. Some do include a `META-INF/spring.provides` file which IDEs can use to offer context-assistance with POM updates. The main reason for choosing an "empty" jar over POM packaging is that they are easier to use (you don't need to remember to add `<type>pom</type>`). I agree with the other commenters, use a build system which supports dependency management otherwise you won't get any benefits of the starters.

Answer (score 4):

Simply stated they are dependency descriptors that list transitive dependencies with versions that are tested to work together to save you time from trying to put libraries together that take care of some facet of an application.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get maven to report the dependencies required by the various spring-boot-starter-* defined in spring boot project pom.xml file, by using the following command

```
mvn dependency:resolve
```

For example with spring 1.5.8.RELEASE, the following jars (and versions) are used

Note format is Group Id:Artifact Id:Version:Scope

```
The following files have been resolved:
    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
    org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
    aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
    org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
    org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
    org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.6.0:test
    org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:test
    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
    org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.4.0:test
    org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
    com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
    org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:test
    org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
    com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
    org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.23:compile
    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
    org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api:jar:8.5.23:compile
    org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
    org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.5.Final:compile
    javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
    org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.23:compile
    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.10:compile
    org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test
    org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.23:compile
    org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
    org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
    ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.11:compile
    org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
    org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:test
    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
    org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:test
    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
    org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
    org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
    org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
    org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
    org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
    org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
    junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
    org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
    net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:test
    net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
    org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
    ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11:compile
    org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.10:compile
```

Just ignore the jars that have a test scope for deployment.

If you do not have spring boot project handy, just create one at [Spring Initializr](http://start.spring.io), with whatever spring boot starters you need. It also uses [maven wrapper](https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper), which wraps the maven command, saving you time setting up and installing maven separately.

So just download the zip file from Spring Initializr, unzip and open a command prompt in the unzipped folder, and use the following command instead

For Linux/Mac OS

```
 ./mvnw dependency:resolve
```

For windows

```
 ./mvnw.cmd dependency:resolve
```