# Is there a spring data redis mapping the Redisson framework

Tags: spring-data-redis, redisson

As the title says, was there a spring data redis mapping to the Redisson framework (http://redisson.org)

Comment: There is no Spring Data integration with Redisson.

Comment: redisson has a package to work with spring data redis.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short answer**

There is [Spring Data Redis integration](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/tree/master/redisson-spring-data)

**Long answer**

Consider [Spring Data Redis integration](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/tree/master/redisson-spring-data) as another type of *connector* or *binding* (check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#redis:connectors) for the *connector* term). The library provides `RedissonConnectionFactory` (`implements RedisConnectionFactory`) which would be the base for working with e.g. `@RedisHash` and spring cache abstraction (`@EnableCaching`). There's also a [redisson-spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/tree/master/redisson-spring-boot-starter) but make sure not to have `lettuce` or `jedis` in classpath because `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration` (provided by spring-boot-autoconfigure) might create a `RedisConnectionFactory` before `org.redisson.spring.starter.RedissonAutoConfiguration` (provided by redisson-spring-boot-starter)!

Comment: What's the difference between both of them?

Comment: redisson-spring-boot-starter is a Spring Boot starter over Spring Data Redis integration

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28273660/5506988 OK so i know what spring boot starter is now.

Answer (score -1):

1. **Add redisson-spring-boot-starter dependency into your project:**

   `compile 'org.redisson:redisson-spring-boot-starter:3.13.5'`
2. **Add settings into application.settings file**

**common spring boot props:**

```
spring:
      redis:
        database: 
        host:
        port:
        password:
        ssl: 
        timeout:
        cluster:
          nodes:
        sentinel:
          master:
          nodes:
    
        
      redisson: 
        file: classpath:redisson.yaml
        config: |
          clusterServersConfig:
            idleConnectionTimeout: 10000
            connectTimeout: 10000
            timeout: 3000
            retryAttempts: 3
            retryInterval: 1500
            failedSlaveReconnectionInterval: 3000
            failedSlaveCheckInterval: 60000
            password: null
            subscriptionsPerConnection: 5
            clientName: null
            loadBalancer: !<org.redisson.connection.balancer.RoundRobinLoadBalancer> {}
            subscriptionConnectionMinimumIdleSize: 1
            subscriptionConnectionPoolSize: 50
            slaveConnectionMinimumIdleSize: 24
            slaveConnectionPoolSize: 64
            masterConnectionMinimumIdleSize: 24
            masterConnectionPoolSize: 64
            readMode: "SLAVE"
            subscriptionMode: "SLAVE"
            nodeAddresses:
            - "redis://127.0.0.1:7004"
            - "redis://127.0.0.1:7001"
            - "redis://127.0.0.1:7000"
            scanInterval: 1000
            pingConnectionInterval: 0
            keepAlive: false
            tcpNoDelay: false
          threads: 16
          nettyThreads: 32
          codec: !<org.redisson.codec.FstCodec> {}
          transportMode: "NIO"
```

3.**Use Redisson through spring bean with RedissonClient interface or RedisTemplate/ReactiveRedisTemplate objects**

Comment: I am still trying to think how this answer is helpful. Copy-paste from https://github.com/redisson/redisson/tree/master/redisson-spring-boot-starter but does not answer even part of the question.

Comment: Agreed this is a blatant copy paste with no effort.