# Error: Could not find or load main class when using eclipse as an IDE

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm new to spring boot. I use eclipse as an IDE. When I'd tried to run this class as a Java Application. But it gives this error. This is a starter project that created using start.spring.io. How to fix this?

The error: [image]

Comment: I see a red squiggly under @SpringBootApplication. Do you have proper imports in your class for it ? import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication; Is it a maven or a gradle project ? Share more information about your project

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Especially: Please read [no pictures of exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) / [no pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Then use the [edit] link to replace screen shots of text with nicely formatted/indented text within your question.

Comment: And finally: I think you are overburdening yourself. You seem to lack basic understanding java, yet you try to not only use eclipse, but also go into a complex framework like spring boot. Honestly: this can't work. And if at all, you should follow a tutorial that gives step by step guidance how to get things to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the spring `jars` into your `classpath`.

This is possible via `package explorer` rmb (right mouse button) `properties` then go to `Java Build Path`.

In the Tab `Libraries` you have to add the `spring-boot-starter` jars.

[[SO] What are `spring-boot-starter` jars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28273543/what-are-spring-boot-starter-jars)