# Mvn:package spring boot - not include starter-* jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven-3

maven package command does not includes `spring-boot-stater-*.jar` in generated jar

Fresh Spring boot project - [Spring Initializr to Download project I used](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=3.1.3&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=web,integration,actuator) with any starter-* dependency,

```
mvn clean package
```

[image]

As shown in picture `Dependecy:tree`(Left) starter JARs are missing in actual JAR generated

Why this Starter-* jars are missing in final packaged JAR?

**UPDATE:**

- Tried changing spring boot version to 2.7.15  - same result

Answer (score 1):

These starter jars don't contain anything useful. They are mainly a mechanism to include other sets of dependencies/jars. It's not harmful for Spring to purposefully strip them out when building the jar.

I found this question [What are `spring-boot-starter` jars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28273543/what-are-spring-boot-starter-jars) and this comment was useful:

> The starter jars themselves are effectively empty as far as your application is concerned. Some do include a META-INF/spring.provides file which IDEs can use to offer context-assistance with POM updates. The main reason for choosing an "empty" jar over POM packaging is that they are easier to use (you don't need to remember to add pom).